# 'fopen' in C can't open existing file in current directoy on Unix

Tags: c, linux, unix, fopen

I am using [fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)(3) in C to read file and process it. The file is present in current working directory where the binary exists, but I am unable to read the file (Linux environment / [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) environment).

Here is the sample code:

## C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

FILE *inFile;
static char fileName[255];

int process_file(FILE *inFile)
{
    char ch;
    inFile = fopen(fileName,"r");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        perror(fileName);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
       // Process file
    }
    fclose(inFile);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Enter filename to process \n");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    process_file(inFile);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I have file permissions set to 777 in the current directory. The resulting binary as well as my source code reside in this directory where the input file exits. Why is the file not opened?

## Update :

```
This question was written in few years back and this code could be improved a lot.
1. The process file should accept char * or char array instead of file pointer
2. unused variables can be removed
3. unused libraries or include files can be removed
4. Can make use of argv to accept filename with path from cmdline
5. return instead of exit in process_file and also proper return code instead of returning 0 from process_file.
```

Comment: And what error do you get? What does the `perror` line output?

Comment: I tried your program, it works fine for me.

Comment: Error in opening file...

Comment: Hi riklunk, In cygwin i am getting this error, i am yet to try in linux environment, could you try it in linux ?

Comment: I am running Linux. It is working for me. Is the file in the same directory as the binary?

Comment: Yes it is..but i only tried in cygwin yet to try it in linux

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work in cygwin either.

Comment: That can't be the *complete* error from the `perror` call.

Comment: Not sure when I tried this code under code::blocks IDE using mingw compiler it is worked fine .. only not working in cygwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have asked this question little more elaborate...

I had three functions to process the same file, like process_fil1e1(), process_file2() and process_file3() even though I called fclose() in all three functions. Somehow the file handle was not closed that properly or the file pointer pointed to EOF or some undefined behavior. It was not working fine.

When I used a single process file and rewind() together, it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the *inFile* and *fileName* as global. You should change your function prototype from

```
int process_file(FILE *inFile)
```

to

```
int process_file()
```

This would at least make your program more clear. Now regarding your problem: It would almost certain be that you are doing something wrong in the input file (like not putting in the file extension) in your input. Remember, you need to pass the complete file name (including the extension which on some systems like Windows (by default) would be hidden). Otherwise, the logic looks correct to me, and it should work fine.

Comment: Since both variables are global, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks for pointing it out. I did not notice at first time. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to input file name with its extension. This may cause problems with reading the file.

If you know the extension of the file you can input only the name and after that make the program add the extension. After `scanf("%s", fileName);` add `strcat(fileName, ".txt");` if you want to enter only the name without extension and the file you read has extension `.txt`.

Your `inFile` and `fileName` variables are extern so you don't need to have arguments for the function `process_file();`, any function can access those variables.

You can change function `int process_file();` to `void process_file();` and delete `return 0`, you don't need that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions , it is a test code , the problem is it is only not working in cygwin environment and working in linux, codeblocks ide, mysys